# 'In the upcoming days'

Tags: phrase-usage

I want to use this phrase in an email to my previous supervisor to let her know that I will send her my essay in the near future.

Does the phrase "in the upcoming days" sound normal to a native English speaker and also convey the intended message?

Comment: It may depend where you are. "Upcoming" sounds American to me. In Britain it would be quite sufficient to say "In the coming days..."

Comment: I would agree with @WS2 that "in the coming days" is more natural in Br English. However "the coming days" can be a very extended period. I would would say "in the coming few days" or, more colloquially "in the next few days".

Comment: ***in the near future*** is idiomatic. *in a few days* is also idiomatic, as is *in the next few days*; but both the last two are ambiguous and can be interpreted to mean 3 days or 30 days; because *few* does not say much, and in a communication such as this, it can be used to be ambiguous on purpose: "some more or less short period of time*. So, I would either use *in the near future*, which is less ambiguous, or I would be explicit and state how many days, even if it's an approximation, as *within the next X days*. or *within the next X weeks*. Otherwise, you are not saying much.

Answer (score 1):

"In the upcoming days" sounds fine to me as a AmE speaker, but there a lot better ways to say it. E.g. in british english "in the coming (few) days" is more natural.

One idiomatic phrase is "in the near future" or "in a few days" or the "next few days".

Comment: 'Fine' and 'but there are [ways that are a lot better]' don't seem to harmonise.

Answer (score 0):

In Australian English, "in the upcoming days" sounds strange. "In the coming days" is acceptable but probably too formal, I agree with @BoldBen's comment that "In the next few days" is a better choice. "In the next couple of days" also works, and arguably implies a slightly shorter time frame (the next few days could be 1-4 days, whereas the next couple of days probably means 2-3 days)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds accurate but as a threat rather than a promise. I'd soften the phrase a bit by stating it as "I will provide my answer to you *Shortly*. That would take the curse off your earlier statement.