# How to refer to an upcoming month/season/year?

Tags: future

I wanted to know what is the correct way to address a certain day/month/season (I apologize in advance that I might have written the title wrong)

For example, when referring to the summer of 2020 (assuming we are speaking about it in April 2020), which way is applicable and which one is not -

1. "I have a competition this summer."
2. "I have a competition next summer."
3. "I have a competition in the upcoming summer."
4. "I have a competition this upcoming summer."

I pretty sure 2 and 4 are wrong, but I am asking here to be certain.

In addition, if there are more than one correct way, when should I use one way and not the other and which one will be more formal?

Comment: Your question is mostly answered here: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/3841/191178

Comment: In a future construction, "I V-phrase competition this summer" means between now [the time of speaking] and the end of the year. "I have a competition next summer" means in the summer of the year following the utterance. (3) sounds unnatural and (4) outlandish. // See also [Does 'in the upcoming days' sound natural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/444489/in-the-upcoming-days).